# Add scripts with grunt build

Tags: gruntjs

I want to add scripts based on grunt build. I want that when I run grunt build-dev to call different scripts and when I call build-dist other ones. I have tried processhtml it works fine but remove all other scripts

```
processhtml: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                "index.html": ["index.html"],
                "login.html": ["login.html"]
            }
        },
        dev: {
            files: {
                "index.html": ["index.html"],
                "login.html": ["login.html"]
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: please paste your code

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to build different scripts to the same targets scripts. Then the script filename you load doesn't change.

Ex: release build bundles a.js and b.js together to www.js but dev build bundles a.js, b.js and debug.js into www.js.

Html file always references www.js (with a cache-breaking parameter of course like build date or something so changing the build will update the script)